# Does there exist nonzero eigenvector such that $E(v) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

This is a followup to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411783/generator-operator-of-v).

Let $\text{U}_+$ be an associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with two generators $E$, $H$, and one defining relation $HE - EH = 2E$. Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional $\text{U}_+$-module. Does there exist a nonzero eigenvector $v \in M$, of $H$, such that $E(v) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the important part. Let  $v $ be an eigenvector for $h $. Then

$$ hev = (2e+eh)v = (\lambda +2)ev, $$

so $ev $ is also an eigenvector for $h $ with eigenvalue $(\lambda+2) $. But $M $ is finite dimensional. Can you complete the argument?